# In my view collection I added a search bar and it filtered the cells but when I click the cell it it self it the path didn't change

Tags: swift, xcode, collections, storyboard

In my view collection I added a search bar and it filtered the cells but when I click the cell it self the path didn't change the path remain the same as it was before the search .

When I click the cell, it should take you to a specific page. Excuse my poor code but I just started to learn swift. And my problem might be super easy and obvious so bare with me please

This is my code I'm using swift storyboard

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class resViewViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var background: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var resL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
    
    var resources:[resFile] = []
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    //dummy data
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var filtered:[resFile] = []

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nipCell = UINib(nibName: "resourceCellCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
     
        //
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        ///
        
        collection.register(nipCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        loadResources()
    }
    
    func loadResources(){
        db.collection("Resources").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
            if let e = error {
                print("There was an issue retrieving data from fireStore. \(e)")
            }else {
                if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents{
                    for doc in snapshotDocuments{
                        
                        let data = doc.data()
                        if let rName = data["ResName"] as? String, let aName  = data["authorName"] as? String, let pName = data["pubName"] as? String, let desc = data["desc"] as? String, let urlName = data["url"] as? String {
                            let newRes = resFile(name: rName, author: aName, publisher: pName, desc: desc, urlString: urlName)
                            self.resources.append(newRes)
                         
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.collection.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
//                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                        self.collection.reloadData()
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//end loadResources
    //search
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = resources.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.collection.reloadData()
    }
}//end of class


extension resViewViewController:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let w = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 110)/2
        return CGSize(width: w, height: 160) //154
    }//end size
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
               return filtered.count
           } else {
        return resources.count
           }
    }//end count
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            
        let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! resourceCellCollectionViewCell
        
        if(searchActive) {
            cell.name.text = filtered[indexPath.row].name
        } else {
        cell.name.text = resources[indexPath.row].name
        }
        return cell
    }//end cell
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "si_resourceListToDetail", sender: indexPath)
    }//end
}//extention

extension resViewViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "si_viewResToPost", let vc = segue.destination as? resPostViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier == "si_resourceListToDetail",
                  let vc = segue.destination as? detailedResViewController, let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            vc.resource = resources[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}//extension

extension resViewViewController: resPostViewControllerDelegate {
    func resPost(_ vc: resPostViewController, resource: resFile?, added: Bool){
        vc.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if added, let r = resource {
                self.resources.append(r)
                self.collection.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}//extension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexPath will always be the same if you select the first visible cell in the UICollectionView. You must check the underlying data set to get the difference..

Also: In Swift it's convention to have capital first letter of classes and structs.

You must do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item: ResFile
    if searchActive {
        item = filtered[indexPath.item]
    } else {
        item = resources[indexPath.item]
    }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "si_resourceListToDetail", sender: item)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let item = sender as? ResFile else { return }
    // Send item to destination view controller
}
```

Comment: i just updated my code can you check it again because i already  have a prepare function

Comment: okay never mind i fixed it but thank you for letting me know about the indexPath it helped a lot (: